# ListViewItem not clickable in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I know there are a few anwsers to this question but none were working in my case. Im trying to make a ListView with a custom adapter in a fragment and the items are not clickable. This is my OnItemClickListener:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("Klick", "Klick");
        HeroItem heroItem = (HeroItem) heroSelect.getItemAtPosition(i);
        int id = heroItem.id;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = HeroDetailFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(id));
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_selecthero, fragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

The OnItemClickListener is set in the OnViewCreated like this:

```
    heroSelect.setClickable(true);
    heroSelect.setAdapter(new HeroSelectAdapter(getContext(),array));
    heroSelect.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Here is the XML for the Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemList"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/heroselect_avatar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heroselect_avatar"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/heroselect_avatar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/heroselect_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the one for the Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="io.rocketfox.overwatchinfo.HeroSelectFragment"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:id="@+id/content_selecthero">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_heroes" />
```

The click on a item is just not triggering anything and after hours of trying to fix it I figured to ask you all! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: remove this line of code heroSelect.setClickable(true); and check.

Comment: wow that worked...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `heroSelect.setClickable(true);` from your code.